# Isolate the name of the city from an address

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, sql

I have a data set in CSV format that includes the name of the store, full address, latitude and longitude (from Geocode).

Since address is in full format, is there a way I can get a special column that would only show the city where the store is located?

I don't know how to work in Python/SQL or other program languages.

Comment: Address is in full format does mean it's stored like `12345 Duffcity, Duffroad 67`?

Comment: Paste an excerpt of the full text of the address and someone could get a clue based on it

Comment: "The Emporium Shopping Complex, Unit 1 P 12-15 , M. Floor, 622 Sukhumvit Road, Klongton Sub-district, Klongtoey District
  Bangkok, 10110, Thailand"

Comment: and you want to get "Klongtoey District Bangkok"? or are you aiming for "Bangkok"?

Comment: All lines are structured in the same way?

Comment: I want just Bangkok in that example. I'm afraid they're not all in the same fashion (were taken directly from the webpage of the store), here's an example from Bahamas: "PO Box N3741
  Paradise Island, Bahamas"

Answer (score 1):

Use **Regular Expression**

> \w*\b"

will find the last word before the quote "

and either and/or combine

> \w*\b,

will find the last word before the comma '

(depending on your original file structure.)

You may be better off standardizing your addresses before this step.

start here 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_reg_expressions.htm

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to parse the address.  If you feed the address into a geocoder it will often do the parsing for you.  The results of most geocoding algorithms is not only the lat long values of the location but a parsed version of the address that was fed in.

Here's a link to a bunch of online batch geocoders that you could use to process your csv file.

https://researchguides.uoregon.edu/geocoding/free-batch